# jQuery filter and find combined in order

Tags: jquery

Hy, I ve got a set (var content) of two elements:
firstly a img-Element and
secondly a p tag which contains many elements (img-Tags as well).

Now I want to get all img-Elements within the set and subelements.

```
I've got content.filter('img').add(content.find('img')).
```

But I want the items in the order they a appear within the set or html-document.

Therefore I wrote a function:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    filterAndFind: function(selector) {
        selector = selector.toLowerCase();
        var els = $([]);
        this.each(function() {
            if(this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == selector) {
                els = els.add($(this).clone());
            }
            els = els.add(selector, $(this));
        });
        return els;
    }
});
```

But when I do a

```
content.filterAndFind('img').wrap('<div class="slides_page"/>')
```

they appear not in the right order.

Does anyone know how to tackle this.

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle with your code?

Comment: Well, I created a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Rsfbd/). But strangely its not IMG 1, 3, 2 but IMG 1, 2, 3. It's exactly what I want but don't know why it's in this order ;)

Comment: Does the problem occur only your testing environment?

Comment: No in the testing environment it works but on production side not.
Lets pretend I have:
`code`
body >
  p > Blablabla
  img 1
  p >
    img 2
  img 3
`code`
What is the right way to filter out all img out of the set body.children(). I thought when I do a filter('img').add(find('img')) I'm loosing the order of the elements. But on jsFiddle it's appearing in document order.

Comment: because the search *(the .find() command)* goes from top to bottom it should be in the order the elements are in the DOM. Misalignment of elements, however, can be caused by asynchronous load (elements are found while they are being added) or because of strange formatting (maybe you are missing some closing tags)